# Tensor Flow using Error

Tags: tensorflow

I have installed TensorFlow and I am able to import it as well.

However using this code

```
from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib
```

I get the error

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.python'

else when I use this

```
from tensorflow import device_lib
```

I get the error

> ImportError: cannot import name 'device_lib'

I am unable to figure out the problem as I have installed tensorflow according to the steps provided in an instruction.

Comment: I guess it might be the version's problem. Because `from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib` is ok for me with python 3.5, tensorflow '1.1.0' by pip installed tensorflow.

Comment: Should I remove Anaconda and re-install it?

Comment: No need, you can read my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the version of python by 'python' and change the version by `conda install python=xx` which xx is the version. And upgrade the version of the tensorflow by `pip install --upgrade tensorflow`